# dependency_overrides does not override dependency

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependency-injection, fastapi

The following FastApi test should use my `get_mock_db` function instead of the `get_db` function, but it dosen't. Currently the test fails because it uses the real Database.

```py
def get_mock_db():
    example_todo = Todo(title="test title", done=True, id=1)

    class MockDb:
        def query(self, _model):
            mock = Mock()
            mock.get = lambda _param: example_todo

        def all(self):
            return [example_todo]

        def add(self):
            pass

        def commit(self):
            pass

        def refresh(self, todo: CreateTodo):
            return Todo(title=todo.title, done=todo.done, id=1)

    return MockDb()


client = TestClient(app)


app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = get_mock_db


def test_get_all():
    response = client.get("/api/v1/todo")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == [
        {
            "title": "test title",
            "done": True,
            "id": 1,
        }
    ]
```

Comment: You may have to add the code where get_db is used in order to see what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key is to understand that dependency_overrides is just a dictionary. In order to override something, you need to specify a key that matches the original dependency.

```py
def get_db():
   return {'db': RealDb()}

def home(commons: dict= Depends(get_db))
   commons['db'].doStuff()
 
app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = lambda: {'db': MockDb()}
```

Here you have inside the `Depends` function call a reference to `get_db` function. Then you are referring to the exact same function with `dependency_overrides[get_db]`. Therefore it gets overridden. Start by verifying that 'xxx' in these two match exactly: Depends(xxx) and dependency_overrides[xxx].

It took some time to wrap my head around the fact that whatever is inside the `Depends` call is actually the identifier for the dependency. So in this example the identifier is function get_db and the same function is used as key in the dictionary.

So this means the following example **does not** work since you are overriding something else than what's specified for Depends.

```py
def get_db(connection_string):
   return {'db': RealDb(connection_string)}

def home(commons: dict= Depends(get_db(os.environ['connectionString']))
   commons['db'].doStuff()

# Does not work 
app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = lambda: {'db': MockDb()}
```